# objective c Class code not executing? what is my problem?

Tags: objective-c

Having some issues with code not executing within the classes I created and thought I initialized and implemented correctly here are all the files. There is a class with an array of another class. Then implemented in the code finally but for some reason none of the NSLog calls seem to execute except the one immediately before [mobdefs createTable] in the main code. All help appreciated...

```
// Mobdefs.h
@interface Mobdefs : NSObject {

    @public NSMutableArray *mobInfo;
}

@property(retain) NSMutableArray *mobInfo; 

-(void) createTable;

@end

//  Mobdefs.m
#import "Mobdefs.h"
#import "Mobrec.h"

@implementation Mobdefs

@synthesize mobInfo;

- (id) init
{
mobInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
return self;
}

-(void) addmobrec
{
MobRec *aNewMobRec = [[MobRec alloc] init];
aNewMobRec.mName=@"newbie";
[mobInfo addObject:aNewMobRec];  
[aNewMobRec release]; 
NSLog(@"MobRec Added\n");  
}

-(void) createTable 
{
NSLog(@"Populating mob table.\n"); // *** THIS CODE NEVER SEEMS TO GET EXECUTED
}

@end


//main.h
Mobdefs *mobdef;  


//main.m 
NSLog(@"just before createTable call\n");
[mobdef createTable];
```

although the createTable code is called in the main the only NSLog output I get is the 'just before createtable...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that you have initialized `mobdef`.  Add the following:

```
mobdef = [[Mobdefs alloc] init];
```

to your `main.m` before you invoke the method on it.

Objective-C silently ignore calls on `nil`, as `mobdef` would be initialized to initially.

Comment: hmmm I do this in main:

Mobdefs *mobdef;

I thought that when a pointer was created as such its init was called inherently. Is this not the case?

Comment: hmmm I do this in main:

    Mobdefs *mobdef; 

I thought that when a pointer was created as such its init was called inherently. Is this not the case? Ah I did that and it is now working, I guess I was wrong an explicit call to init needs to be fired. I really thought init was called automatically by the assign - funny how you can get warnings of an unused int but a non allocated class is ignored.

Comment: reference declaration outside methods (fields, static variables, etc) always get initialized to `nil` initially.  You explicitly need to initialize them properly.  references declared in methods without initialization could be assigned garbage and the compiler warns against that.

Answer (score 0):

are you allocating and initializing mobdef in main.m?